# geolocation with Maxmind GeoLiteCity, cannot read db file

Tags: php, geolocation

Does anyone have any idea why my server cannot read the database file?

No matter what I try, I keep getting the same error:

'Can not open GeoLiteCity.dat'

No explanation. The file is there, i've tried uploading to make sure it wasn't corrupt. I'm using the pure php module. Both files are in the same directory...

I'm trying to set this up on wordpress, might that be part of the issue?

my code is just the basic tester:

```
    include("geoip.inc");

// read GeoIP database
$handle = geoip_open("GeoLiteCity.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);

// map IP to country
echo "IP address 62.149.130.132 located in " . geoip_country_name_by_addr($handle, "62.149.130.132") . " (country code " . geoip_country_code_by_addr($handle, "62.149.130.132") . ")";

// close database handler
geoip_close($handle);
```

but it just wont do it.

Comment: what are the file permissions?

Comment: Please check `is_readable("GeoLiteCity.dat")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try using the full path to the .dat file.
- Make sure that the .dat file is in a directory that the web server process can read.
- Make sure that the .dat file itself is readable by the web server process.

Comment: Brill. That was it. Not sure why, maybe because the dat file was in a plugin and was being called in a template (although via the class in the function... so it was finding all other relative files). But yup, a path relative to the server worked a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up the correct permissions on the file? On linux, make sure the file can be read by the webserver user (usually www-data).

As a quick test you could try chmod the file to 777.

If that solves the issue then you know thats your issue, and if you want, you can then alter the permissions for best security (i.e. chown it to the www-data user and chmod it to suit)

Also ensure the path that the geoip class is looking in for the database is the correct one. These are the only 2 issues i can think of which would cause this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using filesystem path e.g

BEFORE EDIT:

```
$gi = geoip_open('GeoLiteCity.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);
```

AFTER EDIT (FIX):

```
$gi = geoip_open('/var/www/html/googletitan/GeoLiteCity.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);
```

The above change fixed same error for me.